# Selecting and using JSON array values

Tags: php, json, xml, session-variables

I'm currently working on a shopping application but i stumbled upon a problem. The problem is that i can't select the JSON values from my "shopping cart". See the following code and description.

So by using add to cart buttons and such i'm creating the shopping cart. The shopping cart is actually a `JSON` object. An example of the cart:

```
{"cartItems":{"2":{"id":"2","name":"Blouse","price":26.99,"size":"M","quantity":"3","total_product_price":80.97},"5":{"id":"5","name":"Bedrukte Zomerjurk","price":30.5,"size":"L","quantity":"4","total_product_price":122}},"totalPrice":202.97,"totalItems":2,"customerSelect":{"id":"1","firstname":"John","lastname":"TestStefans"}}
```

As you can see the design of my `JSON` cart is:

```
cart:{"cartItems":{"id":{ product information }}}
```

The problem now is trying to select the values like the "name" and "price". This due to the `"id"{` segment. But i need that piece for removing one item by id from the cart.

So my question is:

How would i be able to select all the product information and create an `foreach` for placing the information in the database / email template. I've been trying this but this only gave me the first product:

```
$cart_encode = json_encode($_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']);
$cartDecode = json_decode($cart_encode);
// Adding the product items
            foreach ($cartDecode as $key => $cartItem) {
                $resource->associations->cart_rows->cart_row->id_product = $cartItem->{"id"};
                $resource->associations->cart_rows->cart_row->id_product_attribute = 1;
                $resource->associations->cart_rows->cart_row->id_address_delivery = 1;
                $resource->associations->cart_rows->cart_row->quantity = $cartItem->{"quantity"};
            }
```

Take note that i'm using `XML` for database input. For the email template i've tried:

```
$testName = $_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']['name'];
$testPrice = $_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']['price'];
$testQuantity = $_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']['quantity'];
$testTotal = $_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']['total_product_price'];

$testProduct = array(
    "Name:" => $testName,
    "Price:" => $testPrice,
    "Quantity" => $testQuantity,
    "Total" => $testTotal
);
```

Iknow that the `id number` is missing but i cant dynamicly avoid that layer.

I hope that my question is clear

As always. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the foreach, where does `$resource` come from? Edit: In fact, any of the properties you are chaining.

Comment: @JustCarty They are from an `xml` object requested over an `api` `$resource = $opt->children()->children();` and `$opt = $webService->get(array(
                'resource' => 'carts',
            ));`